# Python : The most efficient way to join two very big (20+ GB) datasets?

Tags: python, join, dictionary, lookup

I have a 21 GB dataset df_ns:

```
domain|ns
123.com|ns1.domanihost.com
hymi.net|ns2.hostinger.com
```

and another 12 GB dataset df_ip:

```
ip|domain
28.76.2.2|myname.com
86.90.234.5| 123.com
```

and I would like to join them on domain name and for the domains that are in both files extract ip and ns.

The way I thought of using it is loading the df_ip data into a dictionary and going through df_ns data line by line and check if the domain is there, then extract the ns. But it is still very resource consuming .

Does anybody have any other, more efficient idea how to do it?

Comment: How about using [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)?

Comment: Are you open to non-Python solutions? Here's an efficient solution: `sort -o df_ns.csv df_ns.csv && sort -o df_ip.csv df_ip.csv && join -t'|' df_ns.csv df_ip.csv > df_combined.csv`

Comment: @Robᵩ Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -o df_ns.csv df_ns.csv && \
sort -o df_ip.csv df_ip.csv && \
join -t'|' df_ns.csv df_ip.csv > df_combined.csv
```

Reference: http://linux.die.net/man/1/join

Answer (score 2):

Sort your data by first column, e.g., with gnu sort.
After that, you will not need to store your data in memory, just use two iterators like this:

```
import csv, sys
it1 = (csv.reader(open("df_ns", "r")))
it2 = (csv.reader(open("df_ip", "r")))
# skip the headers
it1.next()
it2.next()
try:
    dm1, ns = it1.next() # first row
except StopIteration:
    sys.exit(0)
try:
    dm2, ip = it2.next()
except StopIteration:
    sys.exit(0)
while True:
    if dm1 == dm2:
        print dm1, ns, ip
    if dm1 < dm2:
        try:
            dm1, ns = it1.next()
        except StopIteration:
            break
        continue
    try: 
        dm2, ip = it2.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.Since it1 and 2 are lists, they cannot be assigned to two values like dm1,ns. Do you have any other idea how to do it?

Comment: You're welcome. It1 and 2 are not actually lists, they must be iterators that yield tuples. Why do you want them to be _assigned_ to two values?

Comment: I do not want it. But currently I receive an error of too much value to unpack on the first "try-catch" of your answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't test the code -- I gave it just to illustrate the idea. But if there are too many values to unpack, then it means that your csv-files are probably not two-column comma-separated values... Would you please add smth like "row = it1.next(); print row;  dm1, ns = it1.next()" so that we can see what happens?